# How to submit integer value starting with 0 from jsp page to servlet?

Tags: jsp, servlets

I have a jsp registration form which contains Zip Code as one of its field which accepts 5 digits integer number as an input. But now problem is, if input contains digit '0' as starting digit then digit '0' will be ignored when form is submitted. I am getting only 4 digits in my servlet class.

Example : If input is 02345

```
      I will get 2345 in my servlet, but expected value is 02345.
```

Comment: Can you show the form and the code in your servlet where you receive the value?

Comment: Treat the input as text which can only contain digits it is not a number.

Comment: Thanks for all replies.Actually problem was, I was storing zip code as integer, storing it as string solved my problem. Before posting this question I would have seen my model class once it was saving my time as well as others who read this post.

Answer (score 0):

Actually problem was, I was storing zip code as integer, storing it as string solved my problem. Before posting this question I would have seen my model class once it was saving my time as well as others who read this post